# How to create Android timetable layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Could someone tell me how to create the Android layount similar as in the picture?

[image] (Schedule Deluxe Plus)

I trying table layout, but capabilities are quite limited ....for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use a `RelativeLayout` and calculate the height of each element depending on the height of the timetable. If you know that 12h are 320dp or whatever then 1min would be ~0.4dp

And for the entries you could make your own widget.